# Prevent update if data has been updated MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

If I have a document A in mongoDB, client X and Y both retrieved A, client X send request updated A to A1, now client Y send request trying to update A to A2, what's the design pattern used in mongoDB to reject Y's request?

Comment: MongoDB 4 supports transactions. Have a look at them. https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you can use is called [Optimistic Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). Basically the idea is pretty simple, you need additional field which will represent document's version. It might be any kind of timestamp or simple number representing version.

```
db.col.save({ _id:1,  version: 1, field: "A" })
```

Then both client `X` and `Y` retrieve that document. Client `X` updates to `A1` incrementing `version`

```
db.col.update({ _id: 1, version: 1 }, { $set: { field: "A1", version: 2 } }) // or $inc
```

It works since both matching conditions are fine. Then client `Y` tries to set `A2` using the same code

```
db.col.update({ _id: 1, version: 1 }, { $set: { field: "A2", version: 2 } })
```

But this will give you following result:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Which means that no document was modified since specified `version` does not match the one in the database.

Then you can handle that in your logic reloading that document for client `Y` or throwing some sort of concurrency exception.